# MongoDB normalization vs denormalization for my scenario

Tags: mongodb

We're moving our application over to MongoDB after rewriting our back-end in NodeJS. The only thing I can't seem to think through very well is how I should go about handling the storage of `user-to-user` messages. Our application has an instant-messaging feature that is used quite a bit.

To give you a better idea, here are the ways we will query for data.

```
.find(
    { message_to: new ObjectID("...") },
    { message_date: { $gte: timestamp } }
)
```

Fairly simple, get all of the messages that have been sent to the user since the last `timestamp` where `timestamp` is the time that the user last pulled messages. This way we're only requesting the new messages.

What I'm trying to figure out is which way would be better to handle this type of data...

Denormalization:

```
{
    participant_one: ObjectID("..."),
    participant_two: ObjectID("..."),
    messages: [
        {
            message_from: ObjectID("..."),
            message_to: ObjectID("..."),
            message_type: "TEXT",
            message_data: "Hello message",
            message_date: new Date()
        },
        {
            message_from: ObjectID("..."),
            message_to: ObjectID("..."),
            message_type: "TEXT",
            message_data: "Hello message",
            message_date: new Date()
        }
    ]
}
```

Or should I do something like this...

```
{
    participant_one: ObjectID("..."),
    participant_two: ObjectID("..."),
    messages: [
        ObjectID("..."),
        ObjectID("..."),
        ObjectID("..."),
        ObjectID("..."),
        ObjectID("..."),
    ]
}
```

Where the `messages` array lists ObjectID's in another collection that holds the messages in this format:

```
{
    message_from: ObjectID("..."),
    message_to: ObjectID("..."),
    message_type: "TEXT",
    message_data: "Hello message",
    message_date: new Date()
}
```

Please keep in mind that `user-to-user` messaging is a very, very core feature in our application and it's used quite frequently. Currently the average amount of messages between active users is 600/conversation.

Comment: What's the difference between participant_one / two and message_from / to? Are the participants different than the actual sender / receiver of the message?

Based on the query you show, in the normalized scheme, it looks like you could query directly against the messages collection, avoiding a join until you had to screen by participant.

Comment: @Hashcut - There are no differences. The participant_one/two is part of a larger data structure where they are used as indexes to quickly grab a relation between two users.  Message_from / to are simply to figure out who's sending the message. Message_to is not required ultimately, as in user-to-user messaging the recipient is always the user that is not the sender.

Answer (score 0):

If the vast majority of your queries are going to be by message_to and message_date, I would suggest a third structure of collection messages:

```
{
    participant_one: ObjectID("..."),
    participant_two: ObjectID("..."),
    message_from: ObjectID("..."),
    message_to: ObjectID("..."),
    message_type: "TEXT",
    message_data: "Hello message",
    message_date: new Date()
},
```

This essentially inverts the relationship you have, and makes participant one/two subordinate to the message. The advantage is that with this structure, you remain normalized, and you can create quite complex queries on all message attributes very easily.

Also, With mongo, it's easy to aggregate results, so that if you need an array of all messages associated with your participants (like your denormalized example above), a simple find query or aggregation can return that (and it'll be fast too if you create indexes on the participant fields).

Conceptually, also, this structure better models your data: the message is the fundamental document, and all these other fields are attributes (including participant, etc.).

If you already have an application coded (you mentioned you're transitioning a pre-existing codebase to node.js), the best thing to do is to create a test database with the three different structures, then run your application's queries against all three and see which ones give you the best performance with the simplest queries / code.